# AWS S3 bucket used as repository to store files for download to application with Angular front-end?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3

AWS provide SDKs to make developing clients for uploading/downloading to their S3 buckets. I'm building a download client that is an Angular front-end, SpringBoot/PostgreSQL back-end. One of the features of the app is the ability to download large (500MB) files from storage. S3 has been suggested as a possible solution for operational reasons.

Since there is an SDK I can use with Angular I can bypass the SpringBoot part of my app and download directly to the client. I think this sounds logically like a good idea because if the download was S3 -> SpringBoot - > Angular client, that's two hops versus one for S3 -> Angular. However, I see a limitation with giving the client direct access in that the credentials could be exposed thereby giving a user to the entire bucket and not just that content that was meant for them.

I have seen an example of an S3/SpringBoot/Angular project. Should I follow that example and use caching to store large files in memory on the SpringBoot application server, or is there a better way? Simply store the files on the Java application server?

Comment: Why just not create a signed url when generating the GET response where you load w.e it is that has the option to download said file and pass that down to the front end?

Comment: Thankyou SomeStudent, this is what I was looking for.